# Stackdump when trying to write vectors to file

Tags: c++, c++11

Outputs correctly but still getting this when the program executes.

> 0 [main] program 12704 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to '''program.exe.stackdump

The text file looks like this

> U101 77 62 91 95
>   U102 73 0 100 62
>   U103 0 0 39 55
>   U104 84 69 70 100
>   U105 93 86 70 0

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> write(vector<string> students, vector<string> student_scores);

vector<string> write(vector<string> students, vector<string> student_scores)
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Data/scores.txt");
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int exams = student_scores.size() / students.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= students.size(); i++) 
    {
        outfile << students[i] << " ";
        outfile.flush();
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < exams; k++)
        {
            outfile << student_scores[count] << " ";
            count += 1;
            outfile.flush();
        }
        outfile << "\n";

    }
    outfile.close();
    return students;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> students;
    vector<string> student_scores; 

    students.push_back("U101");
    students.push_back("U102");
    students.push_back("U103");
    students.push_back("U104");
    students.push_back("U105");

    student_scores.push_back("77");
    student_scores.push_back("62");
    student_scores.push_back("91");
    student_scores.push_back("95");

    student_scores.push_back("73"); 
    student_scores.push_back("0");
    student_scores.push_back("100");
    student_scores.push_back("62");

    student_scores.push_back("0");
    student_scores.push_back("0");  
    student_scores.push_back("39");
    student_scores.push_back("55");

    student_scores.push_back("84");
    student_scores.push_back("69");
    student_scores.push_back("70"); 
    student_scores.push_back("100");

    student_scores.push_back("93");
    student_scores.push_back("86");
    student_scores.push_back("70");
    student_scores.push_back("0");  

    write(students, student_scores);
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: That's too much code to go through to locate the source of the error, IMO. Please reduce that to a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: `using namespace std;` and then defining your own [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is just asking for confusion!

Comment: I apologize I've fixed the compiler errors! I defined my own stoi because it crashed when I used it and this was a workaround after I did a bit of googling.

Comment: @KevinRamnauth what is the input?

Comment: 11 22 33 44 55, Its supposed to insert a new score for each entry, which it does in the command prompt.

Comment: The logic in `insert_scores` seems completely broken. You need to debug and/or redesign this function.

Comment: Thanks, I intended to do so later as it worked for the time being could it be the way the function constructs the vector that could cause the issue while writing?

Comment: @melpomene thank you for the article it helped alot!  I've isolated the problem

Comment: @RSahu Sorry for the code salad I posted earlier, it was my first time. Took your advice and did just that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over one too many students, on this line:

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= students.size(); i++)
```

You should change it to:

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    ----------------------------^ removed the equal sign
```

Also, you should not use `using namespace std;` or do `outfile.close();`, for the latter you should rely on [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly, I feel silly now